# Fentons Reagent tips: H₂O₂ + FeSO₄

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I've been having trouble with reducing COD (Chemical Oxygen Demand) below approx. 500 ppm by using Fentons Reagent.

For 100 gm of the sample (initial COD 3000 ppm) I use 5 gm of 30% $\ce{H2O2}$ & 0.1 gm of $\ce{FeSO4}$. pH is adjusted to between 3 to 5. Temp. is approx. Room Temp. & I've tried reaction times up to 6 hrs.

Do these sound reasonable choices?

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in Fenton chemistry but [it appears that difficulty in getting the Fenton reagent to reduce COD to below 500 ppm is not unusual.](http://www.h2o2.com/industrial/fentons-reagent.aspx?pid=143&name=General-Chemistry-of-Fenton-s-Reagent)

1. Does your particular wastewater have  chelants such as phosphates, EDTA, formaldehyde, and/or citric/oxalic acids?
2. Perhaps at long reaction times all the iron you add is being precipitated as iron (hydr)oxides.  Could you lower the pH further?

> Reaction rates with Fenton’s Reagent are generally limited by the rate
>   of $\ce{.OH}$ generation (i.e., concentration of iron catalyst) and less so
>   by the specific wastewater being treated. Typical $\ce{Fe:H2O2}$ ratios are
>   1:5-10 wt/wt, though iron levels < 25-50 mg/L can require excessive
>   reaction times (10-24 hours). This is particularly true where the
>   oxidation products (organic acids) sequester the iron and remove it
>   from the catalytic cycle. Fenton’s Reagent is most effective as a
>   pretreatment tool, where CODs are >500 mg/L. This is due to the loss
>   in selectivity as pollutant levels decrease...In addition to free radical scavengers,
>   the process is inhibited by (iron) chelants such as phosphates, EDTA,
>   formaldehyde, and citric/oxalic acids. Because of the sensitivity of
>   Fenton’s Reagent to different wastewaters, it is recommended that the
>   reaction always be characterized through laboratory treatability tests
>   before proceeding to plant scale.

My tip would be to increase the concentration of both $\ce{H2O2}$ and $\ce{FeSO4}$, and, if possible, to make sure the pH is 3 (or maybe even lower).  If that doesn't work, do you think iron chelators could be present in your particular wastewater sample(s)?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. My water sample is expected to have NaCl as an inorganic and only C H O Cl (i.e. no P N S or other elements). In particular it very likely has aromatics, aromatics with sidechains (e.g. Styrene) & -OH groups / Chlorohydrins / Epoxides. No citric nor oxalic acid nor EDTA nor formaldehyde is expected.

Comment: I will try increasing both concentrations but I think I'm already considerably above the conc. given at the link you mentioned. About pH I thought 3 to 5 was the optimum so I was keeping it there. Should I keep it lower? e.g. I read on your link that " it may be necessary to perform the oxidation in steps, readjusting the pH upwards to pH 4-5 after each step so as to prevent low pH from inhibiting the reaction." Apparantly reaction rate is too slow at low pH?